# Python C Header File Parsing and Reverse Initialization

Tags: c++, python, c, parsing, header

I am interested in parsing C header files (only structures and variable declarations) using Python in a recursive manner.

Here is an example of what I am looking for. Suppose the following:

```
typedef struct
{
   double value[3];
} vector3;

typedef struct
{
       unsigned int variable_a[4][2];
       vector3 variable_b[5];
} my_example;
```

Also, suppose there is a file that contains initialization values such as:

```
ANCHOR_STRUCT(my_example) = 
{
    // variable_a
    { {1,2}, {3, 4}, {5,6} ,{7,8}   },

    // variable_b
    { {1.0,2.0,3.0}, {4.0,5.0,6.0}, {7.0,8.0,9.0}, {10.0,11.0,12.0}, {13.0,14.0,15.0}  }
}
```

I would like to be able to parse both of these files and be able to generate a report such as:

```
OUTPUT:
my_example.variable_a[0][0]   = 1
my_example.variable_a[0][1]   = 2
my_example.variable_a[1][0]   = 3
my_example.variable_a[1][1]   = 4
my_example.variable_a[2][0]   = 5
my_example.variable_a[2][1]   = 6
my_example.variable_a[3][0]   = 7
my_example.variable_a[3][1]   = 8

my_example.variable_b[0].value[0] = 1
my_example.variable_b[0].value[1] = 2
my_example.variable_b[0].value[2] = 3
my_example.variable_b[1].value[0] = 4
my_example.variable_b[1].value[1] = 5
my_example.variable_b[1].value[2] = 6
my_example.variable_b[2].value[0] = 7
my_example.variable_b[2].value[1] = 8
my_example.variable_b[2].value[2] = 9
my_example.variable_b[3].value[0] = 10
my_example.variable_b[3].value[1] = 11
my_example.variable_b[3].value[2] = 12
my_example.variable_b[4].value[0] = 13
my_example.variable_b[4].value[1] = 14
my_example.variable_b[4].value[2] = 15
```

I would like to be able to report this without running the code (only through parsing). Is there a Python tool that exist that would parses and prints this information. I'd also like to print out the data type.

It seems it is a bit complicated to parse the "{" and "," and "}" in the intiailization file and be able to match this with the structure's variables and children. Matching the values with the correct code name seems difficult because the order is very important. I also assume recursion is needed for parent/children/grandchildren variables.

Thanks,
Ned

Comment: Possibly of use: https://fedorahosted.org/gcc-python-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you restrict yourself to simple data types, this is going to get very complicated. For example, do you want to handle arbitrary data types such as nested classes?

You say you don't want to run the c-sources, but what you are trying to do here is build your own c-interpreter! Are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel? If yes...

The first thing you need to be able to do, is parse the file. You can can use a parser+lexicographic analyzer such as [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). Once you have the parse tree, you can analyze what your variables are and what their intended values are.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to be able to parse complex data types too, with nested classes.Does PLY handle parsing of the initialization file? If not, do you know of one that can parse the initialization file and match it with the structure's variables?

Comment: If OP really wants to process "complex types", he'll need to be able to look up typedef names ==> he needs symbol tables, at least, in addition to ASTs.  The lesson here is that parsers and ASTs are virtually never enough to do something interesting real languages.  Read my essay on Life Beyond Parsing: www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeBeyondParsing.html

Comment: @Ira Baxter, agreed. And in most cases, I think it would be easier to just run the c-code in question/write wrappers around the c-code to get the information